# Will Ubuntu have full tablet functionality on a Lenovo Tablet PC?

Tags: lenovo, tablet, ubuntu-touch

Considering a Lenovo Tablet PC, (not sure which one yet).

Will UBUNTU work with full tablet functionality including touch screen?

Do any touch screen Tablet PC's work? (Panasonic, HP, Dell, etc...)?

Comment: This is what live cd / usb is for make one for your tablet boot it a choose try Ubuntu. If it works on the live media it will work when installed. As far as I know Ubuntu has full touch support...

Answer (score 2):

The Lenovo Thinkpad X220i Tablet is [Ubuntu certified](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201103-7377/) (for 11.10), as is the [ThinkPad X201](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201002-5341/) (for 10.04).

The Lenovo Ideapad S10-3T (keep in mind that this is a convertible netbook/tablet as opposed to a "pure" tablet) was featured in [this episode](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahKUarZ5fIw/) of the Linux Action Show, and apparently works very well with 12.04 (numerous threads on the Ubuntu Forums indicate that this model is not at all well-supported by earlier versions). If I recall correctly, screen rotation functionality was still lacking, but the LAS guys had set up a simple workaround.

While multitouch was added to Ubuntu a couple of years ago (as per [this article](http://techland.time.com/2010/10/15/ubuntu-netbook-linux-adds-multitouch-looks-tablet-friendly/)) and I have seen YouTube videos of the S10-3T (as well as other tablets) that show multi-touch working very nicely (such as [this one](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CGAQtwIwAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DbcH3flhYHZI&ei=2uIrULqoGMqyyAGVjIHIBw&usg=AFQjCNFrn03tiL76u5U3PjEuwVno2OlCGQ/)), the research I have done has not turned up any information about actually getting this to work, and has yielded many examples of unsuccessful attempts. Basic single-touch functionality is all there though, and I'm sure multi-touch will come soon enough. Until then though, it is worth mentioning that you can use a program called Touchégg to create useful touch gestures.

Answer (score 1):

I had success with an older HP TC1100 with the exception of screen rotation, but it would be best to make a USB boot (or use an external USB CD/DVD drive) and test the hardware from that.

Answer (score 0):

As long as they are built on a Intel chipset, they will probably work quiet well.

**Beware:** Tablets with ARM CPU architecture, built for Windows 8 RT, will **not** work with Ubuntu out of the box, due to the Microsoft Secure Boot feature(?!?)...

There is still a way to make these run  Linux, using Fedora or maybe SuSE Linux

[Microsoft Inks Pact with Fedora Over Windows 8 / Secure Boot](http://www.phonenews.com/microsoft-inks-pact-with-fedora-over-windows-rt-20493/)

[SUSE Linux Outlines Its Plans for Windows 8 Secure Boot](http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/260734/suse_linux_outlines_its_plans_for_windows_8_secure_boot.html)

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for all the Lenovo tablets but I have been running 12.04 on an X60 (tablet-laptop convertible) for some time now and 11.10 before that. 
Most of the functions work out-of-the-box, with a few exceptions. For example if you want to use the tablet stylus with a 2nd monitor hooked in you will need to run MapToOutput to reassign the cursor to the tablet screen only. The screen rotate button doesn't work but you can either use a rotate script as I do or use the Jupiter power app which has a display rotation option. The finger print reader works fine but I set it up on windows before I changed to ubuntu so I cant vouch for that. All the other hardware buttons and function buttons seem to work out of the box.
Again I can only verify this for an X60 so go with the others suggestions and try it out with a live USB.